# Not hide layout when load data in RecyclerView on Android

Tags: java, android

I want develop application for one website and i want load site posts into `RecyclerView`. I want show load layout for first entry in application and when load posts data into `RecyclerView`, **hide** this layout and **show** `RecyclerView`!
I write this codes, but it's not work me and always show `emptyLayout`.
**Main Activity XML :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/appBackground"
    tools:context=".Activities.Main_page">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/main_recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/main_toolbar" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_empty_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <include layout="@layout/empty_page_layout" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity java :**

```
public class Main_page extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final long RIPPLE_DURATION = 250;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private RelativeLayout root;
    private ImageView menu_image;
    private RecyclerView main_recyclerView;
    private MainAdapter mAdaper;
    private List<MainDataModel> dataModels = new ArrayList<MainDataModel>();
    private List<MainDataModel> dataModelsArray;
    private Context context;
    protected Handler handler;
    private RelativeLayout loadLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_page);
        if (!EventBus.getDefault().isRegistered(this)) {
            EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
        }
        handler = new Handler();
        context = getApplicationContext();
        loadLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_empty_layout);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar);
        if (toolbar != null) {
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(null);
        }
        LoadData();
        // Menu
        root = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_root);
        View guillotineMenu = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.menu_layout, null);
        root.addView(guillotineMenu);
        menu_image = (ImageView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_logo);
        new GuillotineAnimation.GuillotineBuilder(guillotineMenu, guillotineMenu.findViewById(R.id.menu_layout_image), menu_image)
                .setStartDelay(RIPPLE_DURATION)
                .setActionBarViewForAnimation(toolbar)
                .setClosedOnStart(true)
                .build();
        // RecyclerView and setData
        main_recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.main_recycler);
        main_recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        main_recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        mAdaper = new MainAdapter(this, dataModels);
        main_recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdaper);

        if (dataModels.isEmpty()) {
            main_recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            loadLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        } else {
            main_recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            loadLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

    }

    @Subscribe
    public void onEvent(List<MainDataModel> mainInfoModels) {
        mAdaper.add(mainInfoModels);
    }

    private void LoadData() {
        final MainDataInfo dataInfo = new MainDataInfo();
        dataInfo.getMainDataInfo(this);
    }
}
```

**AsyncTask code:**

```
public class MainDataInfo {
    private Context mContext;

    public void getMainDataInfo(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        new getInfo().execute(ServerIP.getIP());
    }

    private class getInfo extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        EventBus bus = EventBus.getDefault();
        private String ou_response;
        private List<MainDataModel> infoModels;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            CustomProcessDialog.createAndShow(mContext);
            infoModels = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(ServerIP.getIP())
                    .build();

            Response response;
            try {
                response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                ou_response = response.body().string();
                response.body().close();
                if (ou_response != null) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject postObj = new JSONObject(ou_response);
                        JSONArray postsArray = postObj.getJSONArray("posts");
                        infoModels = new ArrayList<>();

                        for (int i = 0; i <= infoModels.size(); i++) {
                            JSONObject postObject = (JSONObject) postsArray.get(i);
                            int id = postObject.getInt("id");
                            String title = postObject.getString("title");
                            Log.d("Data", "Post id: " + id);
                            Log.d("Data", "Post title: " + title);

                            //Use the title and id as per your requirement
                            infoModels.add(new MainDataModel(
                                    postObject.getInt("id"),
                                    postObject.getString("title"),
                                    postObject.getString("content"),
                                    postObject.getString("thumbnail")));
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return ou_response;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            CustomProcessDialog.dissmis();
            if (result != null) {
                bus.post(infoModels);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

when delete `emptyLayout` from `mainActivity`, `RecyclerView` **show all posts**. when insert this layout (`emptyLayout`) `recyclerView` **is not VISIBLE** and EmptyLayout **is not GONE**!

How can i fit this problem? tnx all <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume that you don't make your call at the good place because *dataModels* is always empty.

Indeed, you have to do your call only after the onPostExecute() method on your AsyncTask which loads your data.

You can use an interface (AsyncResponse in example below) to catch the end of AyncTask process.

Here AynscResponse :

```
public interface AsyncResponse {
    void endTask(List<MainDataModel> dataModels);
}
```

In your AsyncTask :

```
private AsyncResponse listener;

     @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<MainDataModel> dataModels) {
            listener.processFinish(dataModels);
        }
```

Finally in your activity :

```
    // Set by default the visibility
    main_recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    loadLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    public void processFinish(List<MainDataModel> dataModels) {
         if (dataModels.isEmpty()) {
              // Handle error with an empty list
         } else {
              main_recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
              loadLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         }
    }
```

Comment: I inserted my `AsyncTask` codes. please see it and help me with my code my dear friend. thanks